# Rails - Devise - Add action to controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, controller

i got some trouble adding an action in my devise controller.
I created a controller named `registrations_controller` in a folder `users/` like this:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
```

And, there is my route file:

```
root to: 'home#index'

devise_for :users
devise_scope :users do
    get 'users/profil/:id', to: 'users/registrations#profil', as: 'profil'
end
```

And I see the following error:

```
Unknown action
Could not find devise mapping for path "/users/profil/1"
This may happen for two reasons: 1) You forgot to wrap your route inside the scope block. For example: devise_scope :user do get "/some/route" => "some_devise_controller" end 2) You are testing a Devise controller bypassing the router.
```

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    devise_scope :user do
       get 'users/profil/:id', to: 'users/registrations#profil', as: 'profil'
    end
    devise_for :users, :controllers => {:registrations => "users/registrations"}
    resources :users
```

Also you don't need to name the controller `Users::RegistrationsController` keep it named as `RegistrationController` keeping the inheritance as you have `Devise::RegistrationsController`

Comment: What do you mean --> Why does the folder name shouldn't be write ? Also its standard convention as I highlighted from this link: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Override-confirmations-so-users-can-pick-their-own-passwords-as-part-of-confirmation-activation#1-change-render_with_scope-method-to-render-on-confirmationscontroller you'll see in their example they don't call their class `Confirmation::ConfirmationController < Devise::ConfirmationsController` they just simply call it `class ConfirmationsController < Devise::ConfirmationsController`

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment.. I spoke too quickly..

by changing the name of My controller, i now get a new error :
superclass mismatch for class RegistrationsController

Comment: @user2975823 it is okay. Also from here it is highlighted: https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/2343176

Comment: In your exemple, they don't call their class Confirmation::ConfirmationController because the Confirmation controller is in the folder : app/controllers. But mine is in the folder : app/controllers/users/. That's why i'm specifying the folder name by Users::... 
Is it right ?

Comment: Simply have this in your controllers `app/controllers/registration_controller.rb` and inside that at the head of your class you just want `class RegistrationController < Devise::RegistrationController`

Comment: The error is still the same.. "Could not find devise mapping for path"

Comment: Okay.. problem solved.. My bad...

I was writing this : 

devise_scope :users do ...
instead of 
devise_scope :user do ...

The 's' changes everything..
Nevertheless, thanks a lot :) !